# Python: from a dict, how retrieve object as key

Tags: python, key-value

If I have a dictionary of several `Object:value,`, How can I retrieve certain Object using it as `[key]`?

For example

```
class Obj():
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

dct = {Obj(foo):foo_value, Obj(bar):bar_value}

#How to do something like
#>>> dct[foo]
#foo_value
```

Suppose that foo_value can't be aasigned as property of Obj.

So far, this is what I get (abstracted)

```
class Obj():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(tuple(sorted(self.__dict__.items())))
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            return self.__dict__ == other.__dict__
        else:
            return False
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.name)

dct = {Obj('item1'):1, Obj('item2'):2}

print(dct.keys())
dct['item1']
```

And the output

```
dict_keys([item1, item2])
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\ivan\Desktop\multi_e.py", line 197, in <module>
     dct['item1']
KeyError: 'item1'
```

Comment: Change `__hash__` to return `hash(self.name)` and try?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ that doesn't work.

Comment: It returns nothing.

Comment: Why are you doing `dct['item1']` instead of `dct[Obj('item1')]`?

Comment: @user2357112 This is a abtraction. The `Obj` needs a lot of args, but I just want to hash (catch) it with its value property.

Comment: @IvánCastro I think I understood your question, let me know if it worked

Comment: @user2357112 what he is trying to do is not so crazy if you think about it, it's just another way to try to get the obj I think?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ you got a lead about it ;)

Comment: Plz don't down vote me! XD

Comment: @IvánCastro I don't understan the reason of the downvotes... I upvote because I had a nice time trying to solve this...

Comment: @IvánCastro any take on why [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45270094/6768966) doesn't suit your needs?

Comment: Do you really want to store `Obj` instances as key in your dict? I don't see a reason why would that be helpful considering you want to access them using the `Obj.name` later on. Hence, you could drop the `__hash__`, `__eq__` etc completely and make your implementation easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using a custom implementation of `dict`?

```
class FieldDict(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return dict.__getitem__(self, Obj(item))

dct = FieldDict({Obj('item1'):1, Obj('item2'):2})

print(dct.keys())
print(dct['item1'])  # prints 1
```

Comment: @DamianLattenero yes I did. What error are you getting with my code?

Comment: it prints the correct value, and the throws KeyError: <Obj object at 0x7f99373db048>

Comment: @DamianLattenero I wouldn't know about that, works fine without KeyError for me, [look here](http://ideone.com/gDQBl8)

Comment: @IvánCastro well, of course I didn't report the declaration of `Obj`.. try to include that code as well

Comment: @Bit I think it's nice so :), it's a plus one, you can check my answer too if you like

Comment: This solves the problem, and is a short implementation.

Answer (score 2):

That will not work as the keys are not the strings, but they are objects of type `Obj`. Even though all the objects hold that string
You could do this. Store variables as references to objects as keys

```
x = Obj("item1")
y = Obj("item2")
dct= {x:1, y:2}
```

And to retrieve you need to do:

```
>>> dct[x]
1
```

Comment: I think that is not what the OP asked, he don't want to create an instance of Obj

Comment: Thank you for you time. I think there should be a way where I just need to put the `self.value` as key to return the value.

Comment: You could store keys as `Obj("Item1").name` then you could use `self.name` to get the values from the dict

Comment: @IvánCastro: Why are you using the objects as keys in the first place instead of using the object names?

Comment: @anon could you explain your comment to me? your answer is a good first aproach, plus one

Comment: Thanks. What I meant in that comment was because OP wants to retrieve values using the `str` value that the object holds, he would need to set the keys as those `str` values. To use the `str` value in the object, he could make a dictionary by `dct = {Obj("item1").name:1}` and to later retrieve it he could do `dct['item1']` or have a variable hold the value and do `dct[var.name]`

Answer (score 1):

You could roll-out your own dict subclass with custom `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` and you **really**  don't need any complicated `__hash__` method on your `Obj` class after this, just `__init__` will suffice.

```
class Obj:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.name = value

class MyDict(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if isinstance(key, Obj):
            dict.__setitem__(self, key.name, value)
        else:
            dict.__setitem__(self, key, value)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if isinstance(key, Obj):
            return dict.__getitem__(self, key.name)
        return dict.__getitem__(self, key)
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> dct = MyDict()
>>> dct[Obj('item1')] = 1
>>> dct[Obj('item2')] = 2
>>> dct
{'item1': 1, 'item2': 2}    
>>> dct['item1']
1
>>> dct[Obj('item1')]
1
```

Comment: I got `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./prog.py", line 18, in <module>
    dct[Obj('item1')] = 1
  File "./prog.py", line 8, in __setitem__
    dict.__setitem__(self, key.name, value)
AttributeError: 'Obj' object has no attribute 'name'`

Comment: @IvánCastro Does your `Obj` has the `__init__` method similar to my code?

Comment: @IvánCastro Note that my `__init__` implementation was using `self.name` instead of `self.value`.

Answer (score 1):

I was a trying for a little bit time, but I think I got what you want, look:

> edit thanks to @user2357112

```
class Obj():
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __eq__(self, other):
      """Override the default Equals behavior"""
      if isinstance(other, self.__class__):
          return self.value == other.value
      return False

    def __ne__(self, other):
      """Define a non-equality test"""
      return not self.__eq__(other)


    def __hash__(self):
      return id(self.value)

class Custom_dict(dict):

    def __getitem__(self, item):
      return dict.__getitem__(self, Obj(item))

x = Custom_dict()
x[Obj('asdf')] = 5
print(x['asdf'])


dct = Custom_dict({Obj('item1'):1, Obj('item2'):2})
print([key.value for key in dct.keys()])
print(dct['item1'])
```

> 5
>   ['item1', 'item2']
>
> 1

Comment: Reading the answers, looks like it is possible just under a custom dict object

Comment: @IvánCastro and that's the correct to do, when some built in of the program or language don't satisfy your needs, you have to adapt it, extend it or create a new one :). don't forget to vote and accept if it worked for you :)

Comment: Your `Custom_dict` is pretty broken. [Here's a demo of one way in which it doesn't work.](http://ideone.com/OBdaTX)

Comment: @DamianLattenero Can you fix it?

Comment: @user2357112 thank you so much, I missed that, I'm working on it right now

Comment: @anon I didn't, understand your comment, so I fixed it another way, your answer is ok :)

Comment: @user2357112 you are the best! thanks for showing me my error, I fixed that

Comment: Why do you have an `if-else` block when both the blocks execute the same line of code?

Comment: @anon because I'm an idiot? haha, I forget to remove it in my last update, now is not there, thanks for showing me that

Comment: Haha no worries. You don't even need that whole __setitem__() method as all it does is call the superclass' method, which would be inherited anyway

Comment: @anon my friend, absolutely riight, erased, done thanks again :)

Comment: @user2357112 when you can take another look to my answer if you may?